# Rails 3 Form For Custom Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, custom-action

I'm having trouble routing a form to a custom action in Rails 3. Here are my routes:

```
resources :photos do
    resources :comments
    collection do
        get 'update_states'
    end
    member do
        put 'upload'
    end
end
```

Here's the form_for:

```
form_for @photo, :remote => true, :url => { :action => upload_photo_path(@photo) }, :html => { :multipart => :true, :method => 'put' } do |f|
```

And here's the error message:

```
No route matches {:action=>"/photos/42/upload", :controller=>"photos"}
```

... this is especially frustrating because "photos/:id/upload" is *exactly* the correct action for this form.

What am I missing?

EDITS - Here are the original Photo-related routes:

```
   photo_comments    GET    /photos/:photo_id/comments(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
                     POST   /photos/:photo_id/comments(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
   new_photo_comment GET    /photos/:photo_id/comments/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
  edit_photo_comment GET    /photos/:photo_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
       photo_comment GET    /photos/:photo_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
                     PUT    /photos/:photo_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
                     DELETE /photos/:photo_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
update_states_photos GET    /photos/update_states(.:format)               {:action=>"update_states", :controller=>"photos"}
        upload_photo PUT    /photos/:id/upload(.:format)                  {:action=>"upload", :controller=>"photos"}
              photos GET    /photos(.:format)                             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"photos"}
                     POST   /photos(.:format)                             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"photos"}
           new_photo GET    /photos/new(.:format)                         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"photos"}
          edit_photo GET    /photos/:id/edit(.:format)                    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"photos"}
               photo GET    /photos/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"photos"}
                     PUT    /photos/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"photos"}
                     DELETE /photos/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"photos"}
```

Here are the relevant routes when I changed the route to `match 'upload'`:

```
 photo_comments GET    /photos/:photo_id/comments(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
                     POST   /photos/:photo_id/comments(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
}
   new_photo_comment GET    /photos/:photo_id/comments/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
  edit_photo_comment GET    /photos/:photo_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
       photo_comment GET    /photos/:photo_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
                     PUT    /photos/:photo_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
                     DELETE /photos/:photo_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
update_states_photos GET    /photos/update_states(.:format)               {:action=>"update_states", :controller=>"photos"}
        upload_photo        /photos/:id/upload(.:format)                  {:action=>"upload", :controller=>"photos"}
              photos GET    /photos(.:format)                             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"photos"}
                     POST   /photos(.:format)                             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"photos"}
           new_photo GET    /photos/new(.:format)                         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"photos"}
          edit_photo GET    /photos/:id/edit(.:format)                    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"photos"}
               photo GET    /photos/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"photos"}
                     PUT    /photos/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"photos"}
                     DELETE /photos/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"photos"}
```

Unfortunately 'match' didn't work any better...

-- EDIT --

Just to confirm another scenario here... with this in the routes:

```
resources :photos do
    resources :comments
    collection do
        get 'update_states'
    end
    member do
        match 'upload'
    end
end
```

and this in the view:

`form_for @photo, :remote => true, :url => { :action => 'upload' }, :html => { :multipart => :true, :id => 'photo_upload' } do |f|`

I still get:

`No route matches {:action=>"upload", :controller=>"photos"}`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What if you did just `:url => upload_photo_path(@photo)`?

It seems a little strange that you'd be uploading to a member though. Is this just a creation method (in which case you should just POST to the collection path)?

Comment: I may try that later, but I've decided to go in a whole new direction. The reason for uploading to a member is that I was creating, preparing, and saving when the user clicks 'new', then they are actually editing the record as they fill in the information for the first time. I did this because I want to be able to save their progress as they go, and there are several associated models that need the parent id in order to properly save.... anyway, this was too much pain, so I'm trying to come up with a new approach entirely.

Comment: Well just so you know, if only you hadn't used the `{ :action => ... }` bit – and instead did what I suggested above – you would've succeeded. What you were telling the url generation helper to generate was, in fact, that you wanted to post to an action on your controller that was named the output of `upload_photo_path(@photo)` – which **itself** contains the controller and action names (as you can see in the "No route matches..." error)

Comment: Ok, I did a test of this to be sure, and you're right, this did create the path as you said. I'm not going to use it this same way anymore (other problems with my implementation), but this is a valid solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and finally worked through to a solution which I'm not sure was reached in the above case, since the original poster moved on to another approach.

My routes had

```
resources :members  do
  member do
    get "invite" 
    post 'register'
  end
end
```

And "rake routes" included

```
register_member POST   /members/:id/register(.:format)    {:protocol=>"http", :action=>"register", :controller=>"members"}
```

Yet I kept getting the error

```
Started POST "/members/149/register" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-13 13:18:35 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/members/149/register"):

Rendered /Users/lisa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@stv/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.1ms)
```

and the problem was limited only to the form generated by Rails according to the below form_for (note I confirmed this using HTTP client to manually POST to the URL and saw it was finding the route)

```
<%= form_for @account, :url => register_member_path(@account.id) do |account_form| %>
   ...
```

I checked the method, I checked the path, everything looked good.  What I finally noticed, scouring the generated form line by line:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/members/149/register" class="edit_member" id="edit_member_149" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="74pkMgRHfdowSfzjJGMILkAsivVNrJZ0iWYXRUgxyF0=" />
  </div>
...
```

Notice the hidden input name="_method".  I wish the fact that Rails was interpreting this as a PUT had shown up in the logs, that would have made my debugging a lot faster.  I fixed it by telling the form explicitly to use the POST method, which of course it was already, but telling it that removed the hidden _method override.   I assume there's some facet about @account which triggered Rails to use the _method parameter, but @account should be an existing record.

Comment: Interesting, that may have affected me as well, but because I used `match` instead of `post` in my routes it should have worked either way in my case. Great addition to this question though, as I'm sure others will find your solution useful!

Answer (score 1):

Your `url` parameter should be

:url => { :action => "upload" }

---

(Original reply)

I would bet it's because your route expects a `PUT` and your form is sending a `POST` (probably because `@photo = Photo.new`). You have several options:

1. Change your route to `post 'upload'`
2. Create your form with `form_for @photo, :as => :post` with the rest of your arguments
3. Make sure `@photo` is an existing record (e.g. by calling `create` instead of `new`)

The most appropriate choice is probably one of the first 2.

Comment: Well, checking through these: @photo is an existing record for sure. The :method argument is set to 'put' but just to be sure I tried changing the route to post 'upload'... no dice. Using :as=>:post didn't fix it, nor did :as=>:put with the route set to 'put update'

Comment: Try setting the route to `match 'upload'`. Also, post the output of `rake routes`.

Comment: The problem is in your `url` parameter (see updated answer). Sorry for not catching that right away...

Comment: That's what I originally thought too, but no matter which way I put the routes that action gives me `No route matches {:action=>"upload", :controller=>"photos"}`

Comment: If you pass the `url` as in my reply and change your `routes.rb` to have `match` instead of `put`, you still have the same error message?

Comment: Did you restart your server? If yes, what  happens if (keeping `match` in routes), you add a `link_to upload_path(@photo)` in a view? Does that render the correct path?

Comment: I have tried restarting the server, and link_to_upload_path(@photo) works fine...

Comment: What if you add a top-level path `match '/photos/:id/upload' => 'photos#upload', :as => 'upload'` ? Does that work?

Comment: I do think that I figured out at least PART of the problem, though... I'm trying to use this in a multi-step object creation, and it turns out that the code DOES work if I leave the page and then browse back to it. I think this is because the first time you create the record it's loading the new action, which is setting up the object and saving it, then rendering an 'edit' view. However, the URL still says new, even though the @photo object is a saved, current record. So without the ID parameter in the current page URL the form won't render correctly, even though it has a valid existing object

Comment: David, I really appreciate all your help. I'm going to try and take this in a different direction entirely, this whole approach I've been trying is just not worth it.