# rails contact form issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to implement a contact us form on an existing view (the "show" view of a model).

I get a undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class and I'm not sure if I'm implementing things correctly.

In my show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content, "Message" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Send Message" %></p>
<% end %>
```

In my main controller that has all the actions for the site (index, update, show), I added the following actions

```
  # GET /listings/1
  # GET /listings/1.json
  def show
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @listing }
    end
  end


  def newmessage
    @message = Message.new
  end


  def sendmessage
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    if @message.valid?
     #  MessageMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      flash[:notice] = "Message envoy avec succes"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :newmessage
    end
  end
```

And my Message.rb class looks like this:

```
class Message
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :message

  validates :name, 
            :presence => true

  validates :email,
            :format => { :with => /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9a-z\-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\z/ }

  validates :message,
            :length => { :minimum => 10, :maximum => 1000 }


  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end


   def persisted?
     false
    end

end
```

Comment: What is the controller and action name where the form is rendered? You could load the message variable in the action where you render the form @message = Message.new, probably you do that in show action of messages controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def your_action_where_you_render_form
  @message = Message.new
end

def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  if @message.save
    do this
  else
    do that
  end
end
```

when you build a form with `<%= form_for @message do |f| %>` it means you need to init that  variable in the action where the form is rendered as you did in your action called newmessage, but if you want to use that action you'll have to add url to the form somethink like here [Rails 3 Form For Custom Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697176/rails-3-form-for-custom-action)

```
  def show
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    @message = Message.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @listing }
    end
  end
```

Comment: I did init the variable in my action. In fact I have similar code as yours except that my actions are called newmessage and sendmessage. I also added :url => {:action => "sendmessage"} but I get the error undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: seems like url needs to be :url => sendmessage_path, <%= form_for @message, :url => sendmessage_path do |f| %> , also the url depends on what the routes looks like for your sendmessage action when you run rake routes in console

Comment: also, you are saying that you initialized your variable in the proper action, but I doubt it, cause you are rendering the form in the show.html.erb that probably means you are calling show action at that moment and that means you should have @message = Message.new in show action, you haven't posted the show action here so I can't say for sure if you have it where it needs to be, you know it better.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I added the show action in the question. The show action is used to show a particular listing but it also contains the form for the message

Comment: see the show action in my answer, if this action renders your show page it means you must initialize the message here, and now you can even try your form without url, just <%= form_for @message do |f| %>